# Error 404 when trying to create a new React app

Tags: reactjs

I get this error while trying to create a new React app. Installing other components works fine.

Tried all the other posts on StackOverflow. Changed the connection too. Still doesn't work.

Thanks :)

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\reactproject1>npx create-react-app myapp

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\reactproject1\myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T07_33_08_955Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\reactproject1
Done.
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling everything related to react?

Comment: Yes. I Uninsatalled everything and re installed

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.
Don't install other packages or use other registries to patch that, you will mess things up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex is down in South Asian region for some reason, which is the cause of the issue.

If you have a VPN connection, Try connecting to US region. Or wait till it gets back online. :)

Comment: Using a VPN did it. Thanks a Lot. :)